# Python: TypeError: unbound method list.copy() needs an argument

Tags: python, list, methods, arguments, unbound

Given the following methods from a class (sorry the names are in german), but the main question is why do I get an error when calling the method `listeEntfernen` with `liste_links = self.listeEntfernen(self.gewichte, list[x])`. I get the Error: TypeError: unbound method list.copy() needs an argument. I've already tried switching and removing the self keyword and tried calling the function from the class but don't understand why it won't use `list[x]` as a parameter for `liste2` in the `listeEntfernen()` method.

```
   def linkeSeite(self, ziel):
    erg_links = []
    erg_rechts = []
    laenge_k_rechts = 1
    laenge_k_links = 1

    while not erg_rechts:
        komb_rechts = itertools.combinations(self.gewichte, laenge_k_rechts)
        if laenge_k_rechts > len(self.gewichte) or ziel > sum(self.gewichte):
            return
        for x in komb_rechts:
            if sum(x) <= ziel:
                continue
            while not erg_links:
                liste_links = self.listeEntfernen(self.gewichte, list[x])
                komb_links = itertools.combinations(liste_links, laenge_k_links)
                if (sum(x) - ziel) in liste_links:
                    erg_links = sum(x) - ziel
                    erg_rechts = x
                    break
                for y in komb_links:
                    if sum(x) - ziel == sum(y):
                        erg_links = y
                        erg_rechts = x
                        break
            laenge_k_links += 1
    laenge_k_rechts += 1
    return [erg_links, erg_rechts]

def listeEntfernen(self, liste1, liste2):
    erg_liste = []
    liste2_kopie = liste2.copy()
    for i in liste1:
        if i not in liste2_kopie:
            erg_liste.append(i)
            continue
        liste2_kopie.remove(i)
    return erg_liste
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what is purpose of `list[x]`. You do not have your variable `list`, so is `list` still built in object, so then may be that you intend `list(x)`.

Comment: Oh wow I'm so dumb. Thank you so much. Can't believe I spent 30 minutes trying to figure out what was wrong for it just to be the wrong types of parentheses.